# Открыть одно модальное окно

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Добрый вечер, заранее извиняюсь за нубский вопрос, но как открыть только одно определенное модальное окно при клике на разные ссылки? в моем случае открывается сразу два окна. Необходимо решение БЕЗ приязки к id,если, это, конечно, возможно.

вот код того что есть сейчас:

http://jsfiddle.net/S9T7a/

Comment: Которую из тех 2х заготовок, что притаились у вас в примере, вы хотите открыть?

Comment: вот именно, что необходимо открыть каждую, то есть, у модального окна всегда один класс, но при открытии разное содержимое( подразумевается что на странице будет их(модальных окон) несколько, и дабы не плодить классы и разные окна в верстке, необходимо решение которое будет работать с одним дивом модального окна )

Comment: тогда не усложняйте себе жизнь - добавьте каждому модалу специфичный класс или идентификатор и пользуйтесь им.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если по простому, то так:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var modalContent = {
        View: "View Content<button>aaa</button>",
        Edit: "Edit Content"
    };
    var modalBody = $('.ModalContainer').on('click', '.Modal', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //не закрывать если внутри .Modal ткнули
    }).children('.Modal'),
        modalContainer = $('.ModalContainer.CenterModal'),
        body = $('html body');
    $('.mfn-element-btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        body.addClass('NoScroll');
        modalBody.html(modalContent[$(this).prop('title')]); //выбрать содержимое из массива
        modalContainer.addClass('ModalVisible');
    });
    modalContainer.click(function (e) { //закрыть
        e.preventDefault();
        body.removeClass('NoScroll');
        modalContainer.removeClass('ModalVisible');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/S9T7a/3/

Comment: суперб! а в чем минусы данного решения? если вкраце, какие проблемы могут возникнуть? еще раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: никаких проблем особых, просто иногда нужны более сложные решения.